# How to set contacts to show different names based on through which SIM (SIM1 or SIM2) the call is received?

Tags: contacts, calls, dual-sim

I want my Android phone to show a name (for example, Daniel) when a call is received through SIM-1 and a different name (for example, Jon) for the same mobile number when a call is received through SIM-2.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the number of Daniel and Jon exactly the same or do they have different country codes (e.g. +1 and +49)?

Comment: Hy bro. It's actually the same number and the same person. But I want my phone to show two different names based on through which SIM the call is received.

Comment: You can set different ringtones per SIM so when he calls you know the SIM by ringtone.

Comment: Hy bro. Thanks. But I want phone to show different contact names when receiving the call through SIM 1 and SIM 2

Comment: That's not possible.